# Protocols returning Views without AnyView

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to do this following without using AnyView?  I tried an alternative for Thing using associatedtype mimic'ing the View implementation, but couldn't shake a compiler error.

```
protocol Thing : AnyObject {
    var name: String { get }
    var menuItems: AnyView { get }
}

class Movie: Thing {
    var name = "Movie"
    var menuItems: AnyView { AnyView(Button(action: {}) { Text("") }) }
}

class CookieJar: Thing {
    var name = "Cookie Jar"
    var menuItems: AnyView { AnyView(Button(action: {}) { Text("") }) }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var things : [any Thing]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(things, id: \.name) { thing in
            Text(thing.name).contextMenu{ thing.menuItems }
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView(things: [Movie(), CookieJar()])
}
```

Comment: Instead of a protocol thing make it a class. But you should never put views in models. It doesn’t work, a view can adapt to a model

Comment: agree on mixing views/models. this is short form to highlight a particular issue and somewhat besides the point..  I would have Renderer with implementations for MovieRenderer and CookieJarRenderer.

Answer (score -1):

If the code is as you describe, it's straightforward. Require the appropriate type:

```
protocol Thing : AnyObject {
    var name: String { get }
    var menuItems: Button<Text> { get }
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the concrete type everything returns
}

class Movie: Thing {
    var name = "Movie"
    var menuItems = Button(action: {}) { Text("") }
}

class CookieJar: Thing {
    var name = "Cookie Jar"
    var menuItems = Button(action: {}) { Text("") }
}
```

If you mean "can `Thing.menuItems` return an arbitrary View, unknown at compile time, and potentially different for each element," then no, that's literally what AnyView means, and what you got yourself into when you started with `[any Thing]`.

But the normal SwiftUI way to do this is to avoid `any` (and AnyView) and construct everything statically with ViewBuilder:

```
struct Item<MenuItems: View>: View {
    var name: String
    var menuItems: MenuItems
    init(name: String, @ViewBuilder menuItems: () -> MenuItems) {
        self.name = name
        self.menuItems = menuItems()
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(name).contextMenu{ menuItems }
    }
}

struct ContentView<Content: View> : View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView {
        Item(name: "Movie") {
            Button(action: {}) { Text("") }
        }
        Item(name: "Cookie Jar") {
            Button(action: {}) { Text("") }
        }
    }
}
```